# React timeouts and clearing timeouts

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I have a React page that is not setup to be a component. I am looking to use React Hooks, like `useEffect` or any other suggestion. Essentially I need to clear my timeout.

```
const ExamplePage = ({
  test1, test2, test3
}: Props) => {
  const setClipboardTimer = (index, copied, show, delay) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setClipboardData(index, copied, show);
    }, delay);
    // How can I clear my timer on componentWillUnmount
  };

  const copyToClipboard = (copy, index) => {
    copyTextToClipboard(copy);
    setClipboardData(index, true, true);
    setClipboardTimer(index, true, false, 2500);
    setClipboardTimer(index, false, true, 3000);
  };
};
```

Comment: You can accomplish this using useEffect with cleanup: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Like Dom said, if you want a function component you'll have to use the hooks API, if  not that will need to be a class component to leverage mounting/unmounting.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what the other functions do (like copyTextToClipboard,setClipboardData ...etc) in terms of state, the easier way to utilize and to test against timers, would be to use a component class.

For example, this is a simple component class that delays rendering something by 5 seconds:

```
class Timer extends Component {
    state = { requestTimeout: false };

    // **optional** only rerenders the component if the requestTimeout state has been changed
    // this ensures that other state/props changes and/or a parent component 
    // that has its own updating state, won't update this component
    shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) =>
        nextState.requestTimeout !== this.state.requestTimeout);

    // if the component unloads before the 5000ms timeout, clear it
    componentWillUnmount = () => this.clearTimer();

    // a class field to clear the timer that was set in this.requestTimeout
    clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(this.requestTimeout);

    // a class field to update state and clear the timeout
    requestTimedout = () =>
        this.setState({ requestTimeout: true }, () => this.clearTimer());

    // a class field to set this.requestTimeout to a timer that will trigger 
    // this.requestTimedout after a 5000ms delay
    setRequestTimer = () => 
        this.requestTimeout = setTimeout(this.requestTimedOut, 5000);

    // if requestTimeout state is true (?) show hello (:) else show loading
    render = () => this.state.requestTimeout ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>Loading...</p>
}
```

When you start dealing with hooks, then you'll need a way to persist the same timer when/if a mounted functional component is updated while the timer is still running (otherwise, it'll continue to make new timers each time the functional component rerenders).

For example, I have a demo [here](https://react-hooks.mattcarlotta.io/examples/misc#intervaltimer) that involves using `setIterval`. As you can see (click the source `< >` button), it involves utilizing a `useRef` object to persist the same `setInterval` timer when a functional component's state has been updated. Then, I utilize several callback functions to set/pause/clear the interval. In addition, it utilizes the `useEffect` hook to check if it's still running, and if so, it'll clear it in the `return` statement.

In short, while you can achieve the same thing from my setIterval hook demo using a `setTimeout`, I find classes to be easier to work with and understand (especially when the state is being updated and it needs to be handled synchronously).